# How to apply a function repeatedly to get an infinite sequence?

Tags: racket

For example,

```
(require racket/generator)
(define f add1)
(define init 0)
(in-producer (generator () (let loop ([x init]) (yield x) (loop (f x)))))
```

Is there any better way to do this? I don't quite like generators since they have hidden states.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Streams

Using [*streams*](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/streams.html) is probably the easiest:

```
(require racket/stream)

;; X [X -> X] -> [Streamof X]
(define (repeated-fn-stream init f)
  (stream-cons init (repeated-fn-stream (f init) f)))

(repeated-fn-stream 0 add1)
```

#### Sequences

Alternatively, using sequences and [`make-do-sequence`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._make-do-sequence%29%29):

```
(require racket/sequence)

;; X [X -> X] -> [Sequenceof X]
(define (repeated-fn-sequence init f)
  ;; A "Pos" is an X that's the result of applying f repeatedly to init
  (define (pos->element pos) pos)
  (define (next-pos pos) (f pos))
  (define init-pos init)
  (make-do-sequence
   (λ ()
     (values pos->element
             next-pos
             init-pos
             #false
             #false
             #false))))

(repeated-fn-sequence 0 add1)
```

If you wanted to use sequences, *and* you wanted to use [`define-sequence-syntax`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._define-sequence-syntax%29%29) to make `for` loops specialize it:

(this is completely unnecessary for "pure" functionality, but it may have different performance characteristics)

```
(require (for-syntax syntax/parse))

(define-sequence-syntax in-repeated-fn-sequence
  (λ () #'repeated-fn-sequence) ; when used as a normal expression
  (syntax-parser                ; when used *directly* as a for-loop clause
    [[(x) (_ init-expr f-expr)]
     #'[(x) (:do-in
             ([(init) init-expr] [(f) f-expr])
             #true
             ([x init])
             #true
             ()
             #true
             #true
             [(f x)])]]))

(for/list ([x (in-repeated-fn-sequence 0 add1)]
           [i (in-range 10)])
  x)
```

**When using `define-sequence-syntax`, you should make sure that for everything there is a "single point of truth"**. Because of that you often see this pattern:

```
(define-sequence-syntax in-___
  (λ () #'in-___/proc) ; when used as a normal expression
  (syntax-parser
    ....everything that defines the actual functionality....))

;; This is completely determined by the sequence-syntax above,
;; that way there is NO duplicated functionality and NO chance for
;; it to get "out of sync".
(define (in-___/proc parameter ...)
  (for/stream ([elem (in-___ parameter ...)])
    elem))
```

What that means for this is that once you decide you want to use `define-sequence-syntax`, you should define the `repeated-fn-sequence` *function* in terms of it:

```
(define (repeated-fn-sequence init f)
  (for/stream ([elem (in-repeated-fn-sequence init f)])
    elem))
```

That way if the `in-repeated-fn-sequence` needs to be changed to fix a bug or switch representations, the function version changes with it automatically.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize stream-cons is a special form. This seems to use a a lot of  memory. Are streams caching results? EDIT: I am looking into make-do-sequence.

Comment: Yes, they are caching or "memoizing" the results

Answer (score 3):

The best function for this job is an *unfold*… but unfortunately, Racket does not provide a built-in `sequence-unfold` or `stream-unfold` operation. However, there *is* a `stream-unfold` operation in the `srfi/41` library, which will meet your needs. You can see this in action with the following program:

```
#lang racket

(require (only-in srfi/41 stream-unfold))

(define nats (stream-unfold identity (const #t) add1 0))

(for/list ([i (in-range 20)] [n nats]) n)
```

This produces the following output:

```
'(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19)
```

If you don’t want to use `srfi/41`, you can write `stream-unfold` yourself in terms of the `racket/stream` API without too much difficulty, and without any statefulness:

```
(define (stream-unfold mapper pred? gen base)
  (let loop ([base base])
    (if (pred? base)
        (stream-cons (mapper base) (loop (gen base)))
        empty-stream)))
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know it's called unfold.